# Почему файл на SD создается только после перезагрузки девайса?

Tags: android

Создаю файл на SD:

```
File file_log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "xxxxxxLogs/log.txt");
file_log.createNewFile();
```

И пишу в него что-то через OutputStream. Но он не появляется на SD-карте. Вернее, файловые менеджеры на самом устройстве его видят, значит с permission все в порядке, но если подключить к ПК, то нет, и так же если телефон уже был подключен. Был еще планшет и на нем такой код вроде работал, но сейчас его нет под рукой.

Comment: Что за устройство? Процессор случайно не MediaTek?

Comment: Fly FS403. MT6571.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И к компьютеру, наверно, подключается как "Портативный проигрыватель"?
Там после создания файла вот так надо:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
```

Но я делал иначе (взял из исходного кода какого-то встроенного приложения, которое создало файл и он сразу появлялся):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, fileabsolutepath);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Files.getContentUri("external"), values);
```

И то и другое у меня работает.